# Is there a way to use boolean field with aasm gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, aasm

I am using boolean column `is_locked` with `aasm` gem but when I create new record then is_locked column has the 0 value as expected initial but when I try to lock it return true but value doesn't change in the column seems I am doing something wrong.

Can we use boolean for aasm state?

```
class Configuration < ApplicationRecord

  include AASM


  enum is_locked: {
    locked: 1,
    unlocked: 0
  }

  aasm column: :is_locked, enum: true do
    state :unlocked, initial: true
    state :locked

    event :locked do
      transitions from: :unlocked, to: :locked
    end

    event :unlocked do
      transitions from: :locked, to: :unlocked
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Take a look at https://github.com/aasm/aasm#activerecord-enums.